# Elasticsearch-Monitor multiple clusters from single kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, kibana

With 6.2 Elastic version how to have single kibana instance to monitor multiple elastic clusters.

Cluster-1: Production Application cluster
Cluster-2: Log cluster

Need to monitor both the cluster's using single kibana instance with basic license. Is it possible ?

Comment: Use metricbeat to send both cluster's metrics to a single elasticsearch cluster. Use Kibana talking to that ES cluster to create monitoring visualizations like CPU usage, mem usage etc.

Comment: Do we need to add an additional cluster solely for monitoring ? Is it not possible to do it with existing two clusters ?

Comment: No, you can configure metricbeat to send data to one of your existing clusters. Then Kibana connected to that cluster can be used to create visualizations, dashboards etc. You DON'T need one more cluster :)

Comment: i think, the new cross cluster search feature is a option too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/management-cross-cluster-search.html